# Getting the URL for a github project

Tags: git, github

I am looking at a project on github.
It tells me the URL for cloning is:

```
https://github.com/dublintech/backupmedia.git
```

What is the git@... version of this URL then?  Or how do I get it?

Answer (score 4):

There is an "SSH" link just below that URL. Clicking it will populate the textbox with the SSH URL.

Alternatively, subtract `https://`, add `git@`, replace the first `/` with `:`, done.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a fairly recent version of Git, you don't need the `git@` version of the URL. Just do this:

```
git clone https://github.com/dublintech/backupmedia.git
```